# Append to all page titles

Tags: magento-1.8, seo, page-title

I have been asked to append the website name on the end of all page titles therefore my question is what is the best way to dynamically add "- Example.com" to the end of all titles on all pages including catalogue pages.

I could simply just edited the head.phtml and do the following

```
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?> - Example.com</title>
```

But not sure if this is the best way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `System > Configuration > Design > Html Head` their you can see `"Title Suffix"` you can give your title `- Example.com` here which will add in all the page at last

For More Information check http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/11/adding-suffix-or-prefix-to-title-tag-in.html

Comment: Didn't notice you had answered already. Will delete my answer right a way. Cheers